# How to show long event in bootstrap calendar and trim it to stay within the containers width, in .NET Core 7.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, bootstrap-5

**Explanation**

I am building a bootstrap calendar (no Javascript). The calendar works on a weekly event list. The problem i am having is that :

a. If the event is longer than this week it does not show up in the next week.

b. If I plan an event for this Friday, to Next Thursday, it gets out of the calendar containers.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong?

**The frontend markup**

```
<table id="table1" class=" border-0"
   style="width: 100%; display: block; text-align: left;">
<thead class="border-0">
    <tr>
        <th style="font-size:80%;color: lightgray;">
            Nr.
        </th>

        @for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            <th style="font-size:80%;color: gray;border-bottom: 1px solid gray;text-align:center;font-weight:500;">

                &ensp;  @(
            DateTime.UtcNow.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(i).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
            )
            </th>
        }

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var ora in Model.HourList)
    {
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;max-width:160px;">
            <td class="text-secondary" style="text-align:right;">
                <a class="btn btn-sm text-secondary"
                   style="text-align:right;font-size:80%;max-width: 60px;">
                    &emsp; @(hh.HourNumber)
                </a>
            </td>

            @for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++)
            {
                int count = Model.EL.Where(p => p.PreDate == DateTime.UtcNow.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(i)).Where(o => o.HourId == hh.HourId).Count();

                @if (count == 0)
                {
                    <td class="text-secondary border m-0 p-0" style="min-height:50px;max-width:160px;">
                        <span class="border-0" style="color:gray;min-width: 150px;text-align:center;" id="btnCreate">
                            &ensp;
                        </span>
                    </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td class="text-secondary border m-0 p-0" style="min-height:50px;max-width:160px;">

                        @foreach (var item in Model.EL.Where(p => p.PreDate == DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(i)).Where(m => m.HourId == hh.HourId).OrderBy(p => p.HourId))
                        {
                            <div class="dropdown m-1" style="font-weight:500;background-color:green;float:left;
                                                min-width: @(155 * item.LengthId)px;max-height:25px;">
                                <a class="btn btn-sm text-secondary dropdown-toggle border-0"
                                   style="font-size:70%;font-weight:600;"
                                   data-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                    @item.EvDescription
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        }
                    </td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

**The SQL Server tables**

`HourList` table:

```
[HourId]
[HourNumber]
```

`EventLength` table:

```
[LengthId]
[DaysNumber]
```

`EventList` table:

```
[EventId]
[HourId]
[LengthId]
[EvDate]
[EvDescription]
```

**Screenshot 1**: the event gets out of the calendar container length.

[image]

**Screenshot 2**: the long event does not show up on the next week

[image]